# encoding different in Coldfusion and Java

Tags: java, android, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When I encode a string with charset `UTF-8` it gives different results in Java and ColdFusion

**String to encode:**

```
   ONE TWO`< newline >`THREE FOUR
```

**Result in Android (Java):**

```
   ONE+TWO%0ATHREE+FOUR
```

**Result in ColdFusion:**

```
   ONE%20TWO%0D%0ATHREE%20FOUR
```

I thought `UTF-8` defines a standard and every technology follows that while encoding/decoding using `UTF-8`. But it doesn't seem to be the case. Which charset should I rely on?

### Edit:

ColdFusion code to encode the string:

```
<cfset encodedString = URLEncodedFormat(str,"UTF-8")>
```

Java Code to encode String:

```
URLEncoder.encode(str,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: could it be that your coldfusion is windows? android is linux based. So on Window your <newline> is `\r\n` => urlencoded `%0D%0A`. on android newline is just `\n` => urlencoded `%0A`

Comment: One mechanism uses percent-encoding and the other uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding.

Comment: @Fusselchen yes you are right. But is there a standard I could rely on? How can I send/recieve data b/w Coldfusion server and android app?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is **not related to utf-8**. Because there are only plain ascii characters here!

What you are doing is URL encoding, and there are indeed multiple versions of this.

in the HTTP query string, a space is encoded as `+`.

The percent `%` encoding of space is `%20`.

Sometimes you can use either encoding, sometimes you can't... usually, using `+` for spaces, like the Android class did, is more compatible *in my experience*. Because there is a lot of broken code out there that doesn't properly decode.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Well said, does android support UTF-8 encoding ?

Comment: It probably uses utf-8 strings *almost everywhere*, just like Java.

Comment: Note that utf-8 only matters when you have non-english characters. For 7-bit ASCII characters, UTF-8 == ASCII.

Comment: Had some issue while working with multi language text in WebView, any way thank you.

Comment: But if you see my edit, I am using URLEncoding in both coldfusion and java. Still getting different results. Is there a standard encoding that would work same on all technologies?

Comment: Both are valid AFAICT. Nobody said they must be the same.